# why my list changes to a string as I move to another window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote an app using that basis learned there, and this app reads a text file and removes the redundant lines, and returns a list of numbers. The code below returns a list of numbers in `PageOne`, But as I want to use that list in `PageTwo`, it changes to a string. I know I have initially introduced variables as strings, but it does not work under other types as well. How I can keep that as a list?
To run this code you can put a few numbers with space separation in a text file and open it using the app.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
 
 
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Tot_grids = tk.IntVar()
        self.NO = tk.StringVar()
        self.NEW = tk.StringVar()
        self.NEW2 = tk.StringVar()
 
 
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("500x200")
 
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
 
        self.data = Data()
 
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
 
        self.frames[PageOne].button2.config(command=self.go_to_page_two)
        self.show_frame(PageOne)
 
    def go_to_page_two(self):
        self.show_frame(PageTwo)
 
    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()
 
 
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
 
        def opentext():
            my_file = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/pycharm", title="Select your file")
            for T in my_file:  # this line should be here when opening multiple files
                import re
                with open(T, 'r') as infile1:
                    lines = infile1.read()
 
                    nums = []
                    for n in re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+\*\d+)', lines):
                        split_by_ast = n.split("*")
                        if len(split_by_ast) == 1:
                            nums += [float(split_by_ast[0])]
                        else:
                            nums += [float(split_by_ast[1])] * int(split_by_ast[0])
                nums = nums[1:len(nums)]
                data.NO.set(nums)
                label3.config(text=nums)
                label4.config(text=type(nums))
 
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Open file(s)", command=opentext)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
 
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="imported numbers:")
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
 
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="type of imported numbers:")
        label2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
 
        label3 = tk.Label(self)
        label3.grid(row=1, column=1)
 
        label4 = tk.Label(self)
        label4.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)
 
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Continue")
        self.button2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
 
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
 
        self.label5 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.data.NEW)
        self.label5.pack()
 
        self.label5 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.data.NEW2)
        self.label5.pack()
 
        self.data.NO.trace_add('write', self.on_grids_updated)
 
    def on_grids_updated(self, *args):
        self.data.NEW.set(self.data.NO.get())
        self.data.NEW2.set(type(self.data.NO.get()))
 
app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I also wondered why the type of list in PageOne is shown with some random numbers? thanks

Comment: Any value stored in a `StringVar` is, by definition, a string.  There is no such thing as a `ListVar` (since no Tkinter widget directly displays a list), just use an ordinary Python variable here.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please show me that? Do I need to introduce that variable anywhere? and will that variable pass through pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Variable` which is the base class of `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.

`Variable.get()` does not convert the stored data like `StringVar.get()` or `IntVar.get()`.  However it seems that `list` will be converted to `tuple` by TCL internally.

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Tot_grids = tk.IntVar()
        self.NO = tk.Variable()  # used Variable instead of StringVar
        self.NEW = tk.StringVar()
        self.NEW2 = tk.StringVar()
```

Also change the line

```
label4.config(text=type(nums))
```

to

```
label4.config(text=str(type(nums)))
```

will show the type correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes, the string is now a tuple class in PageTwo. So, I used `list()` to convert it back to a list in PageTwo. I see when I also change the class of `NEW` to a `Variable()`, it doesn't affect the code. I wondered why we do not consider all variables as `Variable()` instead of `IntVar` or `DoubleVar`?